# Matching Cards Program - How do I properly create a double array that allows me to compare userInput's value to it and make the game work?

Tags: java, arrays, pattern-matching

I am trying to teach myself java, and found this project online but I can't figure out how to properly put it together. I'm wondering if anyone can help me set up the double array that will ultimately allow me to compare the user input (EX: A1) to whatever the value of that piece is.

GAMEPLAY:
Menu Comes up. User enters 1 to play. 2 to exit.
Game board appears, Looks like this. Behind each box is a letter (a-h)

```
    A  B  C  D 
    -  -  -  - 
1 | .  .  .  . 
2 | .  .  .  . 
3 | .  .  .  . 
4 | .  .  .  .
```

Then user enters a spot (EX: A1). The board appears with the random letter showing.

```
    A  B  C  D 
    -  -  -  - 
1 | b  .  .  . 
2 | .  .  .  . 
3 | .  .  .  . 
4 | .  .  .  .
```

Then it asks again. (EX: user enters C3)

```
    A  B  C  D 
    -  -  -  - 
1 | .  .  .  . 
2 | .  .  .  . 
3 | .  .  d  . 
4 | .  .  .  .
```

If it matches, they stay and the loop starts again. If they don't match, they both switch back to ".".

It keeps going till the whole board is filled and the game is over!

I'm uploading the project here, and have also included what I have so far, though i do not think it is all right!

```
import java.util.*;

public class breitje_MatchUp{
   static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   static int i=0;
   static char[][] clearBoard = new char[4][4]; 
   static char[][] letterBoard = new char[4][4];
   public static void main(String[] args){
      drawBoard();


   }

   public static void drawMenu(){
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Match Up game! \n");  
      System.out.println("Please select from the following: ");  
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");  
      System.out.println("1. New Game");  
      System.out.println("2. Quit");  
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");  
      int optionSelect = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");  
      while(optionSelect!=1 && optionSelect !=2){
         System.out.println("Please enter 1 (New Game) or 2(Quit)");
         optionSelect = input.nextInt();}
      if (optionSelect == 1)
         System.out.print("START GAME HERE********");
      else if (optionSelect == 2)
         System.out.println("Thanks for playing! Have a great day.");  
   }


   public static void drawBoard(){
            for(int row1 = 0; row1 < 4; row1++) {
         System.out.println(""); // this will create a new line for each new row
         for(int col1 = 0; col1 < 4; col1++) {
          clearBoard[row1][col1]='.'; // this will print out the 4 row variable values            
         }        
      }

      System.out.format("   %2s %2s %2s %2s \n",'A','B','C','D');
      System.out.format("   %2s %2s %2s %2s \n",'-','-','-','-');
      System.out.format("1 |%2s %2s %2s %2s \n",clearBoard[0][0],clearBoard[0][1],clearBoard[0][2],clearBoard[0][3]);
      System.out.format("2 |%2s %2s %2s %2s \n",clearBoard[1][0],clearBoard[1][1],clearBoard[1][2],clearBoard[1][3]);
      System.out.format("3 |%2s %2s %2s %2s \n",clearBoard[2][0],clearBoard[2][1],clearBoard[2][2],clearBoard[2][3]);
      System.out.format("4 |%2s %2s %2s %2s \n",clearBoard[3][0],clearBoard[3][1],clearBoard[3][2],clearBoard[3][3]);  


      System.out.println("Please enter a column (A,B,C, or D) and row (1,2,3,or 4). Ex: A3 : ");
      String userInput = input.nextLine();
      userInput = userInput.toUpperCase().trim();


   } 
}
```

I am unsure how to initialize the values of `letterBoard` to represent the initial random placement of the cards. How can I "deal the cards" in my Java code?

Comment: What double array are you referring to/

Comment: @Code-Guru in the project it requires I return a double array for the game board. I just don't know where to go from here and how to compare the userInput to the array

Comment: Let's back up a second. What exactly do you mean by a "double array"? Can you give an example? (I suspect that I am looking for something different than what you mean.)

Comment: @Code-Guru sorry for the confusion. I meant 2D array. array[4][4]

Comment: You already created two 2D arrays called `clearBoard` and `letterBoard `. Are these the arrays you are asking about? What exactly do you need to "set up"?

Comment: So I have then initalized but I'm not sure if I did it properly and i'm not sure how to have another array with the random letters that appear after the user enters in a value(comparing the two arrays). Just kindof confused on the logic I guess. @Code-Guru

Comment: I don't even know what you are trying to do. Can you please edit your question to explain in more detail?

Comment: @Code-Guru just trying to make a matching game on a 4 by 4 gameboard that takes user input and flips over the cards, and if they are both the same, leaves them flipped. But if they arent, they go back to being periods (".")

Comment: Let's back up a few steps. Will you edit your question to describe the  rules of the game? Assume that you are not playing it on a computer. Describe step by step what happens during game play.

Comment: @Code-Guru sorry about that. check out the edit and see if I did a good enough job. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so you need to initialize the values of the array to represent the cards, right? If you played this game without a computer, how would you do it? Can you think of a way to simulate that with a computer program?

Comment: Youd shuffle the cards...The only way I've learned to get random things are integers with .random(). is there a way to represent that with letters? @Code-Guru

Comment: and sorry for the confusion before, i thought i had uploaded a photo with the instructions but apparently it didnt work @Code-Guru

Comment: Ultimately, a `char` is simply a number. To start, can you generate a random number between 0 and 25? (Assuming that you will use the letters from `a` to `z`.)

Comment: @code-Guru would it be (int)(Math.random()*25) well we are only using a-h, so would it be 8?

Comment: Now that we have gotten to a specific question, I edited your original post to include it and posted an answer that I hope helps get you started. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are likely several ways to do this. One possible solution is to do something like this:

```
for each letter from 'a' to 'h'
    pick two random locations
    if the given location is not yet used
        place the letter at the location
```

I have just sketched this out in pseudocode so that you can work out the details in Java on your own. Most likely you will want to write this in its own method and possible create helper methods that the primary method calls in order to perform specific tasks.